# How to render deeply nested associations to json using serializer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, associations, active-model-serializers

I am just working on a simple rails project in which the models have these many relationships between them :

1. A author can have many posts
2. A post can have many comments
3. likes and dislikes belongs to each post

Now, I have rendered the authors data ( in json ) and the output which I am getting is this :

[image]

As we can say that it is rendering only author and post data ( neither comments nor likes/dislikes ).

I am very new to RubyOnRails. So, Whatever I have tried so far is this below :

Controller :

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @auth = Author.find_by(id: params[:id])
        render json: @auth
    end
end
```

Models :

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: post
end

class Dislike < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: post
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: post
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
end
```

Serializers :

```
class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :age
  has_many :posts
end

class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :content, :username
end

class DislikeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :dislikecount
end

class LikeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :likecount
end

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :content
  has_many :comments, serializer: CommentSerializer  
end
```

schema.rb :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_03_25_091544) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "age"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "content"
    t.string "username"
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "dislikes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "dislikecount"
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_dislikes_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "likecount"
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_likes_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "content"
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_posts_on_author_id"
  end

end
```

Now, I just want to render complete data of a author ( Means, The expected output must include author detail + post details + comments + likes + dislikes ) in json form.

I have searched a lot to overcome this issue, but could not resolve this issue.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have the relationship defined on the Post model for Dis/Likecounts. If you added the `has_one` in the model, and then in the serializer along with defining the serializer, that might work

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 changes in your code -

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes
  has_many :dislikes
  belongs_to :author
end

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :content
  has_many :comments, serializer: CommentSerializer
  has_many :likes
  has_many :dislikes  
end
```

Comment: No, but it is rendering same output again.

Comment: I just updated the answer, can you confirm that the post you are trying to test has likes, dislikes and comments?

Comment: Yes I confirm that A post has likes, dislikes and comments. Please Note that the relationship between post and likes/dislikes is one-to-one ( as i have added corresponding attribute of likecount and dislikecount in likes/dislikes models )

Comment: You are thinking that a Post has many likes/dislikes. Whereas I have directly added a separate attribute for the same.

Comment: Are the `comments` loading? Which version of `active_model_serializer` are you using?

Comment: Comments are not loading. How can i check the version of active_model_serializer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210363/discussion-between-gautam-and-vishal-srivastav).